# Setting NS for Subdomain to Another Hosted Zone with Same Apex Domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

Suppose I own example.com.
I delegate the subdomain www.example.com to a particular set of NS that is say a Route53 Hosted Zone. The rest of the example.com zone is not on R53 and contains important information for other subdomain/records. You can consider this Zone 1, and you can consider the new R53 Hosted Zone as Zone 2.

I want to have www.example.com CNAMEd to a particular endpoint, say a cloudfront distribution. 
Since I can't CNAME the apex domain, instead hosted zone 2 is created in R53 with the original apex domain: example.com. 
Then, inside that hosted zone, there is a record for the subdomain www.example.com with the CNAME to xxx.cloudfront.net.

I can't directly configure www.example.com with the CNAME in hosted zone 1 for various reasons, including that the CNAME is always changing and the person controlling the CNAME only has control over zone 2.

So the full chain looks like this: 
User types in www.example.com, they get NS hosted 1 records. In that zone, the record for www.example.com points to Hosted zone 2 records. In this zone (which was created with apex example.com) the record for www.example.com is a CNAME to the proper endpoint.

My question: will any DNS resolvers mistakenly cache the NS from the second zone as apex domain records? Obviously, I want those NS accessed only for the www.example.com records. If example.com NS are mistakenly thought of as in hosted zone 2, there can be a lot of issues.

If this is the case, is there any way to make sure to dns resolvers that the apex domain nameservers are zone 1, and zone 2 records are ONLY for www.example.com, even though they were created with the example.com apex domain?

I understand that there are other ways to do this (CNAME to sep domain, etc) but for logistical purposes (for now) I am only interested in setting the NS directly for the www subdomain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I delegate the subdomain www.example.com to a particular set of NS that is say a Route53 Hosted Zone." Are you sure you want to delegate `www` to other nameservers? While possible, this is highly unusual and comes with its own set of problems. In all cases, you are offtopic here as this is not related to programming, you should look at [sf]  or [webmasters.se] instead, but make sure to read their help section to see what is on topic or not and how to write good questions.

Comment: "will any DNS resolvers mistakenly cache the NS from the second zone as apex domain records?" They will be mistaken if they DO NOT cache that, because in the DNS model the authoritative side on a split is on the children side, so yes this delegation will be cached, and used. I think your main problem is "including that the CNAME is always changing" which is strange, and difficult to understand without any specifics. I think you should try around fixing that specific problem instead of using other solutions that go around but will create you far more problems down the road...

Comment: " What I'm worried about it is that those nameservers are cached for the apex (example.com)" There is no reason for that to happen.